# How can memory destination BTS be significantly slower than load / BTS reg,reg / store?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86-64, cpu-architecture, microcoding

In the general case, how can an instruction that can take memory or register operands ever be slower with memory operands then mov + mov -> instruction -> mov + mov

Based on the throughput and latency found in [Agner Fog's instruction tables](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) (looking at Skylake in my case, p238)
I see that the following numbers for the `btr/bts` instructions:

```
instruction, operands, uops fused domain, uops unfused domain, latency, throughput
mov          r,r       1                  1                    0-1      .25
mov          m,r       1                  2                    2        1
mov          r,m       1                  1                    2        .5
... 
bts/btr      r,r       1                  1                    N/A      .5
bts/btr      m,r       10                 10                   N/A      5
```

I dont see how these numbers could possibly be correct. Even in the worst case where there are no registers to spare and you have store one in a temporary memory location it would be faster to:

```
## hypothetical worst-case microcode that saves/restores a scratch register
mov m,r  // + 1  throughput , save a register
mov r,m  // + .5 throughput , load BTS destination operand
bts r,r  // + 1  throughput , do bts (or btr)
mov m,r  // + 1  throughput , store result
mov r,m  // + .5 throughput , restore register
```

As the worst case this has a better throughput than just `bts m,r` (4 < 5).  (Editor's note: adding up throughputs doesn't work when they have different bottlenecks.  You need to consider uops and ports; this sequence should be 2c throughput, bottlenecked on 1/clock store throughput.)

And microcode instructions have there own set of registers so it seems aggressively unlikely this would actually be needed. Can anyone explain why `bts` (or in general any instruction) could have higher throughput with memory, register operands than using the worst case moving policy.

(Editor's note: yes, there are a few hidden temp register that microcode can use.  Something like `add [mem], reg` does at least logically just load into one of those and then store the result.)

Comment: Note the insane CISC semantics of bit-string instructions; they can index outside the dword addressed by the addressing mode!!  This is what makes it special.

Comment: Your emulation appears to be based on AT&T syntax, with the destination last.  Agner's tables are Intel-syntax, with destination first.  Skylake has 2/clock loads, 1/clock stores, not vice versa (hopefully you realize that this makes a lot more sense.)  I'd recommend using Intel syntax for your example that saves regs, i.e. swap the order of the first 2 lines, and the perf part of the comment, etc.

Comment: I fixed that for you, and left a couple notes about your assumptions.

Answer (score 6):

What you're missing is that BT, BTC, BTS and BTR don't work like you described when a memory operand is used.  You're assuming the memory versions work the same as the register versions, but that's not quite the case.  With the register version, the value of the second operand is used is taken modulo 64 (or 16 or 32).  With the memory version, the value of the second operand is used as is.  This means that the actual memory location accessed by the instruction may not be the address given by the memory operand, but one somewhere past it.

For example, ignoring the need to save registers and atomicity, to get the same operation of `BTS [rsi + rdi], rax` using the register version of BTS you'd need to do something like this:

```
LEA rbx, [rsi + rdi]
MOV rcx, rax
SHR rcx, 8
MOV rdx, [rbx + rcx]
BTS rdx, rax
MOV [rbx + rcx], rdx
```

You can simplify this if you know the value of RAX is less than 64, or if it's a simpler memory operand.  Indeed as you've noticed, it may be an advantage in cases like these to use the faster register version over the slower memory version even if it means a few more instructions.

Comment: Now do `lock bts [rsi+rdi], rax`.   :-)     (Which is the only kind I ever use.)

Comment: @prl Ah, I knew I was forgetting something. Thanks.